# How to create a Class<? extends XYZ> from string

Tags: java

I am trying to create a class from string but want to be of specific type, like:

```
Class<? extends XYZ> aa = Class.forName(messageType);

private ResponseMessage processScore(Map<String, Object> result) {
    Optional<String> messageType = result.keySet().stream().findAny();
    Class<? extends State> aa = Class.forName(messageType.get());
    return messageType.map(messageKey -> extractScore(result.get(messageKey), messageKey, aa)).orElse(null);
}
```

Is it possible in java?

Thanks

Comment: Could you give an example? How does the string look like?

Comment: _Create_ a class? or look up a class?

Comment: What do you mean by "of specific type" ?

Comment: I have added my example, but it is not fully refactored yet.

Comment: I think you're using wildcards incorrectly here.  Does `Class<State> aa = ...` work syntactically?  I think you should use that instead.

Comment: What does create a class mean? Maybe you mean create an instance of a specific type?

Comment: Yes, with a cast. Here is the signature of `forName`: `public static Class<?> forName(String className)`. Why it is not parameterized is another question.

Comment: Actually, it can be one among a set of classes which extends State, so can't check for State.

Comment: What does `extractScore()` do and what is the 3rd parameter `aa.class` meant do do? Note that `aa.class` isn't possible and assuming you want the class you looked up before then that's what `aa` already is, so getting the "class" of `aa` would return `Class`.

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem to accept T, as generics get removed at runtime, and this is a runtime operation. So, it appears this is . not possible at all at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the [`asSubclass` method of `Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass-java.lang.Class-):

```
Class<?> unknownClass = Class.forName(string);
Class<? extends State> stateSubClass = unknownClass.asSubclass(State.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you successfully look up a class via `Class.forName(fqcn)` you might want to check whether it is assignable to `State`, i.e. `State` itself or a subclass. Then you need to explicitly cast to `Class<? extends State>` to tell the compiler that this is ok:

```
Class<?> lookedUp= Class.forName( messageType.get() );

//check the class actually is State or a subclass
if( State.class.isAssignableFrom( lookedUp ) ) {
  //explicit cast needed 
  //Class<? extends State> aa = (Class<? extends State>)lookedUp;

  //as per correct comment by Daniel Pryden use asSubclass(BaseClass)
  Class<? extends State> aa = lookedUp.asSubclass(State.class);

  //use aa
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Thomas, not exact, but I was looking for something similar

Comment: This will give you an unchecked cast warning. You should use `asSubclass` instead, as it incorporates the type check and doesn't produce a warning.